# Material Autocomplete with FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete

I have a formGroup that uses the Material Autocomplete component/input to select a Customer with a name and ID. I am able to select and POST fine. How do I load the Customer name in the same Autocomplete component on a GET by providing the ID from the formGroup?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            formControlName="MarinaCustomerId">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption [displayWith]="displayFunction"
            (optionSelected)="getCustomerVessels();resetVessel()">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
              <span>{{option.LastName + ', ' + option.FirstName}}</span>
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: the value of the FormControl is `this.yourForm.get('MarinaCustomerId').value`.BTW you can use a simple formControl (not inside a FormGroup), just `marinaCustomerId=new FormControl(), <input [formControl]="marinaCustomerId"`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Eliseo.